# WSUS Upgrade Question

Tags: wsus

Do you need to take WSUS server offline to upgrade it from WSUS 2.0 SP1 to WSUS 3.0 SP1 ? Would there be any issues running this upgrade while the Sever is online and clients are connecting to it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the release notes:

*If connections are open to an existing WSUS database, the installation may fail*

*If you are upgrading to WSUS 3.0 SP1 from an existing installation and connections are still open to the existing WSUS database (for example, if SQL Server Management Studio is open), the installation may fail. Please close all connections and reinstall WSUS 3.0 SP1.*

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708525%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IMHO server/service upgrade 'best practices' would suggest the stop/interruption of such services in light of the maintenance being done, **specially** if it's a full version upgrade.

You should also consider if there is the need of (re)configuring new or old settings with the new version before they are automatically sent to your clients.  Plus stopping/starting the WSUS service is really no big deal.